# How to create an instance of another class within a new class at instantiation?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm trying to create a class called B which contains an attribute called news (news being an instance of class A taken at instantiation).

class A has been defined earlier.

However, I'm not sure how to write this in code. I have two attempts below, though I'm not sure if either is correct. Can someone provide some insight?

```
# Attempt 1:    
class B():
    def __init__ (self, news):
        self.news = A()

# Attempt 2:    
class B():

    news = A() # news being an instance of class A

    def __init__(self, news):
        self.news = news
```

Thank you!

Comment: You wrote basically the same thing, you just assign A() to a variable in Attemp 2

Comment: @Adamantoisetortoise: They are not basically the same thing.

Comment: @martineau How so?

Comment: The first create a separate `A` instance every time a `B` instance is created. The second only create a single `A` and signs it — the same one — to each `B` created. The second one is creating what is called a class attribute and assigning it to each instance (which is unnecessary).

Comment: Well right, I thought A() was referring to a specific instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.news = A()
```

You create an instance of `A` by calling `A()`, which you then assign to your instance variable `news`. So now `B.news` is an sintance of class `A`.